# problem with utf-8 windows versus Mac

Tags: tcl, mojibake

OK, I have a small test file that contains utf-8 codes. Here it is (the language is Wolof)

```
Fˆndeen d‘kk la bu ay wolof aki seereer a fa nekk. DigantŽem ak
Cees jur—om-benni kilomeetar la. MbŽyum gerte ‘pp ci diiwaan bi mu
```

that is what it looks like in a vanilla editor, but in hex it is:

```
xxd test.txt
0000000: 46cb 866e 6465 656e 2064 e280 986b 6b20  F..ndeen d...kk 
0000010: 6c61 2062 7520 6179 2077 6f6c 6f66 2061  la bu ay wolof a
0000020: 6b69 2073 6565 7265 6572 2061 2066 6120  ki seereer a fa 
0000030: 6e65 6b6b 2e20 4469 6761 6e74 c5bd 656d  nekk. Digant..em
0000040: 2061 6b0d 0a43 6565 7320 6a75 72e2 8094   ak..Cees jur...
0000050: 6f6d 2d62 656e 6e69 206b 696c 6f6d 6565  om-benni kilomee
0000060: 7461 7220 6c61 2e20 4d62 c5bd 7975 6d20  tar la. Mb..yum 
0000070: 6765 7274 6520 e280 9870 7020 6369 2064  gerte ...pp ci d
0000080: 6969 7761 616e 2062 6920 6d75 0d0a       iiwaan bi mu..
```

The second character [cb86] is a non-standard coding for a-grave [à] which is found quite
consistently in web documents, although in 'real' utf-8, a-grave would be c3a0. Real utf-8 works
beautifully on Macs and under Windows.

I handle the fake utf-8 by using a character map which included the pair { ˆ à } because that
little caret is what cb86 generates, and everything works fine ON A MAC for displaying text (in a text widget)
like this:

```
Fàndeen dëkk la bu ay wolof aki seereer a fa nekk. Digantéem ak
Cees juróom-benni kilomeetar la. Mbéyum gerte ëpp ci diiwaan bi mu
```

On a PC - using the same file (shared) the first three characters read in are
46 cb 20 (using no fconfigure). I have run through ALL the possible encodings
and can never get the same map to work. [There are twenty that will allow 46 cb 86]

Sorry this is so long, but if anyone has a clue, I would love to hear it.

Tel Monks

Comment: The original question has the tag "tcl". What does this have to do with Tcl?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Wolof at all. However, I'm sure that the problem you've got is that you've got a file that is in a mixed encoding, with non-standard code points (instead of standard Unicode) and then a conversion to bytes using the UTF-8 scheme. **This is messy!**

The way to deal with this is to first read the bytes into Tcl using a channel that is configured to use the `utf-8` encoding:

```
set f [open $filename]
fconfigure $f -encoding utf-8
set contents [read $f]
close $f
```

Then, you need to apply a transformation using `string map` that converts the “wrong” characters to the right ones. For example, this would do it (as far as I can tell) for the specific characters you listed:

```
set mapping {"\u02c6" "\u00e0"}
set fixed [string map $mapping $contents]
# You should now be able to do anything you want with $fixed
```

However, that might be all wrong! The problem is that I don't know what the contents of the file *should* be (at the level of characters, not bytes). Which gets back to my comment “I don't know Wolof at all”.

### Update

Now that dan04 has identified what had been done to that poor text, I can provide how to decode.
Read the code in as above, but now we use a different mapping step:

```
set fixed [encoding convertfrom macRoman [encoding convertto cp1252 $content]]
```

On the sample supplied, that produces the expected output.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, but...
These files were originally on a PC, not a Mac. It so happens that the Mac has no trouble with them, but the PC does.
 I do use the fconfigure with -encoding utf-8 - does not help.
I have determined that the "right" thing is happening to output files, but they will not displayu correctly on a PC, nor in the colsole window, nor in a text widget.

I will try the convertfrom and convertto (athough why MacRoman?) and  let you know how it turns out.

Comment: that works ! Thanks, but can you explain it to me? Since there was never a Mac involved before me...

Comment: The file sounds like it started out on an *old* Mac, then was shared with Windows where someone converted it to UTF-8 without understanding (or even looking at) the contents. The converted file (on your *new* Mac) is what you've now got. How this all came about, I have no idea; welcome to the strange life of data! :-)

Comment: Thanks again for getting me over this hump.

Answer (score 0):

The data was originally encoded using a Mac encoding (most likely Roman, but Turkish and Icelandic are also possible for this example), misinterpreted as windows-1252, and then correctly converted to UTF-8.